# Does Python have decorators in the standard library?

Tags: python, decorator

Apart from `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod`?  Most languages have some basic libraries making use of most of the language features.

It seems that many of the decorators I find myself making are things which tons of people would use, but I haven't found any inbuilt python decorators which do them. Are there such things?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) is usually used as a decorator.

[functools](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#module-functools) has several functions normally used as a decorator, such as `total_ordering`, `update_wrapped`, `lru_cache`, and `wraps`.

contextlib has the [`contextmanager`](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator.

Keep in mind, you can use any function as a decorator:

```
@decorator
def function(): pass
```

is just the same as

```
def function(): pass
function = decorator(function)
```

In order to be useful, they generally need to be expecting a callable as an argument and they need to return a callable object. (`property` is an exception to the second part of that.)

Classes can also be decorated, in exactly the same way.

There is also a [list of decorators on the Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary). Some of them are in the standard library, some are not.

Answer (score 10):

- [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property)
- [functools.total_ordering](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)
- [functools.lru_cache](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)
- [functools.wraps](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)
- [contextlib.contextmanager](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager)

  ...

Answer (score 1):

NOt a library *per se* but a compilation of useful decorators are on http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary

Answer (score 0):

Python decorators are just plain functions or other callables which take as single argument the function or class to be decorated. As such you can use many ordinary functions as decorators and vice versa. Possible use as decorator is often not explicitly documented.

Comment: I mentioned this in my answer, with an example.