# How is it decided that a function or module is added to the python standard library?

Tags: python, decorator

I was wondering today why some of the more useful decorators in the [Python Decorator Library](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary) like @memoized haven't been added to the standard python library.

Is there a set of standards under which a module/function/decorator is evaluated in order to become a member of the standard library, or is it the informal decision of some group?

Comment: Just a side note: There's [`functools.lru_cache`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) in Python 3.

Comment: Related: [Does the Python have decorators in the standard library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120342/does-the-python-have-decorators-in-the-standard-library)

Comment: <a href="http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0002/">PEP 2: "Procedure for Adding New Modules"</a>